# C# Regex Pattern Match for specific string

Tags: c#, regex, matching

Trying to do a regex match and replace for a specific pattern to rename files.  Unfortunately I'm not very good using regex and would appreciate any help you can offer.

the pattern I'm looking to replace is.

```
(Conflicted copy * )
```

To explain I need to replace (Conflicted copy *) basically everything that matches the words "(Conflicted copy" pattern and anything between those words and the closing parentheses.

so for example.  Book1 (Conflicted copy some junk here).xls
to :  Book1.xls

What regex would I use for that? To replace?

I've tried the following:   pattern = "\([^\(]*\)";

Unfortunately that doesn't work as there are paths that have () in them.

(ie, C:\Some crap\1.(stuff)\book1 (Conflicted copy junk stuff).xls )

it will fail and rename the file to:

(C:\Some crap\1.\book1.xls) -> then error out because that path doesn't exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you guys.

Comment: Add the "Conflicted copy" into the regexp so it only matches that

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - Thanks for replying.  I would but I don't know exactly where to add it in.  Again not familiar with regex.

Comment: `\(Conflicted copy [^)]*\)` probably will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's very easy to get file extension, you could use this regex to extract filename only :

`[^\\]*(?=\s\(Conflicted copy)`

then append original file extension.

This avoid the use of regex groups by using positive lookahead.

**Explanation**

`[^\\]*` Match anything but a `\` (to exclude file path)

`(?=\s\(Conflicted copy)` followed by a whitespace and *(Conflicted copy*

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6lPGI/4)

**Other solution using groups**

The following regex will extract filename without *(Conflicted copy ...)* and file extension :

`([^\\]*)(?=\s\(Conflicted copy).*?\)(\..*)$`

Group 1 : filename

Group 2 : file extension

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6lPGI/3)

Comment: Updated answer to exclude file paths